# About a right action definition

Tags: group-theory, definition, group-actions

Let's take this group action definition, taken from a textbook I'm reading:

> Given two groups $G$, $H$ and a homomorphism $\phi=G \mapsto \text{Aut}(H)$, we say G acts on H through
> $$h^\sigma=h^{\phi(\sigma)}, h \in H, \sigma \in G$$

Now I've read this definition is actually a right action, which is not highlighted in the original text.
I was wondering why this is a **right action** and I'd like to turn the above definition into a left action as well, to see the difference, possibly.

Thank in advance.

Comment: It is a right action because $(h^\sigma)^\tau=h^{\sigma\tau}$ and $h^{e}=h$ (where $e$ is the identity of $G$).

Comment: Try ${}^\sigma h:=h^{\sigma^{-1}}$.

Comment: Which book are you referring to?

Comment: Groups by Antonio Machí, Springer edition. He introduces this action in the cohomology chapter

Comment: I'm using the Italian version of It, but I guess and hope the English version is matching. A very good textbook, with an unconventional part about Hölder program.